# Image blending in numpy returns plain white image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to blend 2 different images using numpy and not an image library. Since numpy works with arrays I used the formula below to blend the images:

```
    alpha = 0.8
    img_blend = img_1* (1.0 - alpha) + img_2* alpha
    io.imshow(img_blend)
```

For some reason I keep getting a plain white image.
Both images show normally, when I use io.imshow() on them, the problem arises when applying the formula.

Here is the output I playing with the alpha values:

alpha = 0.9995 :

[image: alpha = 0.9995]

alpha = 1:

[image]

alpha = 0:

[image: alpha = 0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While typing the question I figured out what was wrong, so I am going to answer my own question in case anyone would benefit from it.

Adding the 2 numpy arrays was converting my array values from uint8 values to float64 values. The solution I found is by changing the type back to uint8.

```
img_blend = (img_1* (1.0 - alpha) + img_2* alpha).astype('uint8')
```

The big give away was the color bar to the side. The final image is shown below:

[image: blended image]